# Jquery window.open() is not working with '_self' paramter

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am trying to open a link in the same window from a javascript function, but it does not work. I am using window.open with "_self" parameter, but if I use the same function without "_self", it works i.e. it opens the link in a new window. Moreover, as soon ' window.open("http:://www.google.com", "_self")' is called, the page reloads and I get a 304 HTTP error and a ? at the end of url. Can you please suggest how to make this work ? Or is there any alternative to it ? Thank you

```
<html lang="en">
 <body>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="openButton" onclick=open()>Open</button>
  <script src="js/open.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>

js/open.js:
var open = function(){
  window.open("http:://www.google.com", "_self");
}
```

Comment: use window.location.href="http:://www.google.com" to open in the active window

Comment: (i) this is not a jQuery question, (2) why would you want to name a child window "_self"?

Answer (score 1):

Redirect browser to new location.

```js
var open = function(){
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it's still not opening and giving me the same 304 HTTP error.

Comment: "This does not really indicate an error, but rather indicates that the resource for the requested URL has not changed since last accessed or cached". There was also a typo in URL (double colon).

Answer (score -1):

just change your `type="submit"` to `type="button"` ....
Also, and use `window.location.href("URL")`